Error: collection not found when using do_bulk_insert in Milvus
I am encountering an error when trying to use the do_bulk_insert method to create a new collection. The error message indicates that the collection does not exist:
collection not found [database=default] [collection=a552b9ad4_adb1_47e0_9e98_33d913b52757]

Is it necessary to create an empty collection with a schema before performing a bulk insert? I successfully used this method a couple of weeks ago without any issues, which is why I am confused about this requirement now.
